# Как показать клавиатуру одному пользователю в канале telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу телеграмм бота при помощи TelegramBotApi

После того как пользователь вводит команду /game у него должна отобразиться клавиатура с вариантами ответа. Но в канале с другими участниками  она отображается у всех пользователей. Вычитал что `selective` может справиться с этой проблемой. Но при добавлении его в данные клавиатуры (`types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, selective = True, resize_keyboard=True)`) клавиатура не показывается ни кому. Не могу понять как сделать, чтобы selective указывал только на одного пользователя (или группу пользователей) и только ему показывал клавиатуру?

Python 3

Comment: Слушай дружище ты решил проблему? у меня сейчас точно такая же хочу что бы клавиатура показывалась только тому кто написал сообщение для начала диалога, помоги если можешь)

Answer (score 0):

Делай send_message конкретному юзеру, то есть передавай не chat.id а from_user.id

Comment: Тогда клавиатура с вариантами ответов отображается в боте у данного пользователя, а не в канале. Работает но не удобно, хотелось чтобы он в канале видел её

Answer (score 0):

Условие - бот находиться в группе, пользователь вызывает *\команду* и получает персонально(другим участникам группы их не показывает) кнопки.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='bomb')
async def cmd_bomb(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1, selective=True)
      # resize_keyboard=True - уменьшение кнопок к объекту клавиатуры
      # row_width=х разобьёт кнопки на строки по х элемента в каждой
      # selective=True - показа клавиатуры лишь некоторым участникам
    buttons = ['"Небольшой толчок..."', 'Разминировать']
    keyboard.add(*buttons)
    await message.reply('Решается судьба Мегатонны...', reply_markup=keyboard)    
      # message.reply - решает условие
```

Тот, кто вызывает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остальные участники:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]